# redirect from html frames in whole page

Tags: html, redirect

hello friends i am having two frames, each frame has a html form which should redirect to other page, but here the problem is when any of the page is redirecting the target page is seen only in that particular frame only....
when any of the frame's form is submitted how to redirect completely into the whole page...

i am using

```
<frameset cols="40%,60%">
<frame src="pmode.html" frameborder="0">
<frame src="create.html"frameborder="0">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose we have the `target` attribute of the form:

```
<form action="newpage.html" target="_top">
```

This means: "the target of this form is the top most page, not the current frame".

Answer (score 0):

You can also try... <form action="newpage.html" target="_blank">
if you wish to open page in new tab

Answer (score 0):

Jus put **target="_blank"** in the button link of the other page (pmode.html or create.html)